# Delete a key under a condition in Javascript object

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, object, conditional-statements

I need to write a **removeVowelKeys** function that takes an object and removes all keys that begin with a vowel. The register does not matter.

For example, I have an object

```
const vowelsObj = {
  alarm: 'hello',
  chip: 100,
  isValid: false,
  Advice: 'Learn it hard',
  onClick: 'make it great again',
}
```

The result of a function's work should look like this:

```
vowelsObj === {
  chip: 100,
}
```

This is what I've already written

```
function removeVowelKeys(object) {
  const num = Object.keys(object);

  for( let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    for (let key in object) {
    if (key.startsWith('a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u'||'y')) {
      delete object[key];
        }
    }
    }
    return object;
}
```

but it removes only the first field that starts with a vowel and the others stay. Any ideas how it can be done?

Comment: `key.startsWith('a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u'||'y'))`  That doesn't do what you think it does,.. `'a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u'||'y' = 'a'`, IOW: your code does -> `key.startsWith('a')`

Comment: Try this `['a','e','i','o','u','y'].includes(key.charAt(0).toLowerCase())` in your if statement.

Comment: Programing language ain't understand `key.startsWith('a' || 'b' || 'c')` like human, you should translate it to `key.startsWith('a') || key.startsWith('b') || key.startsWith('c')`; Or just `['a', 'b', 'c'].includes(key[0].toLowerCase())`; Or, if you prefer a more compact way, `const removeVowelKeys = object => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(object).filter(pair => !['a','e','i','o','u','y'].includes(pair[0][0].toLowerCase())))`, this line of function will destruct object as key-value pair, then just filter out key that is vowel, and return a new constructed object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the regex `/^[aeiouy]/`. The `^` in the regex matches the start of the string `[aeiouy]` matches one of `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u`, or `y`. To match case in-sensitive (ignore character casing) add the `i` flag. eg. `/^[aeiouy]/i`

```js
const vowelsObj = {
  alarm: 'hello',
  chip: 100,
  isValid: false,
  Advice: 'Learn it hard',
  onClick: 'make it great again',
}

function removeVowelKeys(object) {
  for (let key in object) {
    if (key.match(/^[aeiouy]/)) {
      delete object[key];
    }
  }
  return object;
}


removeVowelKeys(vowelsObj);
console.log(vowelsObj);
```

I've kept `removeVowelKeys` similar to what you already had. However `delete` mutates the argument. If you don't want this, copy the properties that you do want to a new object instead of deleting from the original.

```
const copy = {};
for (let key in object) {
  if (!key.match(/^[aeiouy]/)) { // <- added ! to invert the if-statement
    copy[key] = object[key];
  }
}
return copy;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are simply including an extra for loop outside looping through the keys which are not needed and using `includes` will be helpful than repeating the `startsWith` for each and every character.

```js
const vowelsObj = {
    alarm: 'hello',
    chip: 100,
    isValid: false,
    Advice: 'Learn it hard',
    onClick: 'make it great again',
}

function removeVowelKeys(object) {
    const updatedResult = Object.keys(object).reduce((updatedResult, key) => {
        const char = (typeof(key) === 'string' && key.trim().length > 0)? key.toLowerCase().charAt(0) : '';
        if (!['a', 'e' , 'i' ,'o' , 'u' ,'y'].includes(char)){
            updatedResult[key] = object[key];
        }
        return updatedResult;
    }, {})
    return updatedResult;
}

console.log(removeVowelKeys(vowelsObj));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use individual `.startsWith` calls for each character. Also you need to transform the key to lowercase to remove the uppercase keys.

```js
const vowelsObj = {
  alarm: 'hello',
  chip: 100,
  isValid: false,
  Advice: 'Learn it hard',
  onClick: 'make it great again',
}

function removeVowelKeys(object) {
  const num = Object.keys(object);

  for( let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    for (let key in object) {
      const lowercaseKey = key.toLowerCase()
      if (
        lowercaseKey.startsWith('a') || lowercaseKey.startsWith('e')
          || lowercaseKey.startsWith('i') || lowercaseKey.startsWith('o')
          || lowercaseKey.startsWith('u') || lowercaseKey.startsWith('y')
      ) {
        delete object[key];
      }
    }
  }
    return object;
}

console.log(
  removeVowelKeys(vowelsObj)
)
```